# Unable to cast object of type 'system.data.datatable' to type 'lInqobj.tbl1'

Tags: linq

i am getting this error in

```
property.setAgent(((Agent)Session[FormContract.AGENT]).agent_id.ToString());
```

Unable to cast object of type 'system.data.datatable'  to type 'lInqobj.Agent'

please help me out

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the object found at `Session[FormContract.AGENT]` is not actually an `Agent`, but a `DataTable`, so it cannot be cast to an `Agent`. Try figuring out what is putting that value there, and why it's putting a `DataTable` there rather than an `Agent`.